# Retrieve current address details in Prestashop payment module

Tags: php, payment-gateway, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am creating a Prestashop Payment Integration module for FSSnet (Indian payment gateway).

I need to pass some user defined fields to the Payment gateway, some of which comes from the current specified Order Shipping address (like Phone number, etc.)

While I have extracted most of the fields after scouring through various public classes and global variables, I am still left with Address details.

FYI, I need values like following from AddressCore class (aliased as Address, present in /classes/Address.php):

```
/** @var string Firstname */
public $firstname;

/** @var string Address first line */
public $address1;

/** @var string Address second line (optional) */
public $address2;

/** @var string Postal code */
public $postcode;
```

I thought it was simple enough (or maybe it is), but I am not able to find the correct method to extract these public variables from Address class using member access operators.

Also, I **need to fetch these values from the module's main php file** (mymodulename.php for example), under the **hookPayment** function, and not through SMARTY tpl file. I guess that would've been simpler.

Update::
Found the solution. Had to debug through Address object. 
Following code works.

```
$user_address = new Address(intval($params['cart']->id_address_invoice));
```

and then

```
$udf3 = "udf3=".$user_address->phone;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Joni, I used prestashop's {debug} feature along with the reliable print_r() to list the data in Address object.
Found that I was directly accessing the object, instead of fetching its member.
So, following code saved the Address object with all its values.
$user_address = new Address(intval($params['cart']->id_address_invoice));

Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: Great you got it working :) It's always best to post the code that your try to use to access something.

Comment: Sure thing :)
Will post again if anyone needs more details.

Answer (score 3):

Try This

create an address object by retrieving the id from the current cart.

```
$address = new Address($this->context->cart->id_address_delivery);
```

Comment: This question was asked 5 years ago :D

Comment: yeah, But i thought some one else can get help

Comment: Good thought. Although I had answered my own question, but always good to have multiple suggestions.